# What happened to AddOrUpdate in EF 7 / Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm writing a seed method using EntityFramework.Core 7.0.0-rc1-final.

What happened to the AddOrUpdate method of DbSet?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's waiting to be implemented. See issues [#629](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/629) & [#4526](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4526).

Update: according to comments below (unverified) - this feature is finally slated for release in .NET Core 2.1!

Comment: Your answer is dated one and a half year ago. Is it still waiting for implementation? It seems that it's been dropped all together...

Comment: We came up with an alternative design for seed data, so it won't be implemented as part of that. The other issue is still a possibility.

Comment: hi @bricelam, what alternatives exist today to seed data in EF Core? Could you share them?

Comment: [Data Seeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding) is coming in EF Core 2.1.

Comment: Data Seeding provides upsert on model creating, but what about elsewhere in the application?  For example, if you want to perform an upsert within an action or service endpoint?

Comment: @user1477388 See [Disconnected entities: Saving single entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities#saving-single-entities) in the docs.

Comment: @bricelam Rather than relying on PK, I'd like to determine uniqueness based on three columns.  From the msdn article, I assume I could change `var existingBlog = context.Blogs.Find(blog.BlogId);` to `var existingBlog = context.Blogs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemId == item.ItemId && x.CarrierId == item.CarrierId && x.ServiceLevelId == item.ServiceLevelId);`. I was hoping to avoid the extra database call, though!  What do you think?

Comment: `Find` effectively looks in `context.Blogs.Local` first before sending the query. You could do the same.

Comment: Since EF 2 Update effectively acts as AddOrUpdate, as long as the primary key is auto-generated (eg an identity column).  See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58775548/216440

Answer (score 18):

The following MS Docs article, [Disconnected entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities#saving-single-entities), says that just using an Update will act as an AddOrUpdate from EF Core 2.0 onwards, as long as the primary key column in the database has an auto-generated (eg identity) value.

To quote from the article:

> If it is known whether or not an insert or update is needed, then
>   either Add or Update can be used appropriately.
>
> However, if the entity uses auto-generated key values, then the Update
>   method can be used for both cases.
>
> The Update method normally marks the entity for update, not insert.
>   However, if the entity has a auto-generated key, and no key value has
>   been set, then the entity is instead automatically marked for insert.
>
> This behavior was introduced in EF Core 2.0. For earlier releases it
>   is always necessary to explicitly choose either Add or Update.
>
> If the entity is not using auto-generated keys, then the application
>   must decide whether the entity should be inserted or updated.

I've tried this out in a test project and can confirm that Update works for both adding and updating an entity in EF Core 2.2, with an auto-generated key.

The *Disconnected entities* article linked above also includes sample code for a homemade InsertOrUpdate method,  for earlier versions of EF Core or if the entity doesn't have an auto-generated key.  The sample code is specific to a particular entity class and would need modification to make it generalized.

Comment: I think this should now be the accepted answer. I don't believe the other answers are relevant for anything greater than EF Core 2.0

Comment: I was thinking on doing some magic here and there... luckily I did continue reading

Answer (score 8):

I think this is what you want.

```
public static class DbSetExtension
{
    public static void AddOrUpdate<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet, T data) where T : class
    {
        var context = dbSet.GetContext();
        var ids = context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T)).FindPrimaryKey().Properties.Select(x => x.Name);

        var t = typeof(T);
        List<PropertyInfo> keyFields = new List<PropertyInfo>();

        foreach (var propt in t.GetProperties())
        {
            var keyAttr = ids.Contains(propt.Name);
            if (keyAttr)
            {
                keyFields.Add(propt);
            }
        }
        if (keyFields.Count <= 0)
        {
            throw new Exception($"{t.FullName} does not have a KeyAttribute field. Unable to exec AddOrUpdate call.");
        }
        var entities = dbSet.AsNoTracking().ToList();
        foreach (var keyField in keyFields)
        {
            var keyVal = keyField.GetValue(data);
            entities = entities.Where(p => p.GetType().GetProperty(keyField.Name).GetValue(p).Equals(keyVal)).ToList();
        }
        var dbVal = entities.FirstOrDefault();
        if (dbVal != null)
        {
            context.Entry(dbVal).CurrentValues.SetValues(data);
            context.Entry(dbVal).State = EntityState.Modified;
            return;
        }
        dbSet.Add(data);
    }

    public static void AddOrUpdate<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet, Expression<Func<T, object>> key, T data) where T : class
    {
        var context = dbSet.GetContext();
        var ids = context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T)).FindPrimaryKey().Properties.Select(x => x.Name);
        var t = typeof(T);
        var keyObject = key.Compile()(data);
        PropertyInfo[] keyFields = keyObject.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p=>t.GetProperty(p.Name)).ToArray();
        if (keyFields == null)
        {
            throw new Exception($"{t.FullName} does not have a KeyAttribute field. Unable to exec AddOrUpdate call.");
        }
        var keyVals = keyFields.Select(p => p.GetValue(data));
        var entities = dbSet.AsNoTracking().ToList();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var keyVal in keyVals)
        {
            entities = entities.Where(p => p.GetType().GetProperty(keyFields[i].Name).GetValue(p).Equals(keyVal)).ToList();
            i++;
        }
        if (entities.Any())
        {
            var dbVal = entities.FirstOrDefault();
            var keyAttrs =
                data.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => ids.Contains(p.Name)).ToList();
            if (keyAttrs.Any())
            {
                foreach (var keyAttr in keyAttrs)
                {
                    keyAttr.SetValue(data,
                        dbVal.GetType()
                            .GetProperties()
                            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == keyAttr.Name)
                            .GetValue(dbVal));
                }
                context.Entry(dbVal).CurrentValues.SetValues(data);
                context.Entry(dbVal).State = EntityState.Modified;
                return;
            }                
        }
        dbSet.Add(data);
    }
}

public static class HackyDbSetGetContextTrick
{
    public static DbContext GetContext<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> dbSet)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        return (DbContext)dbSet
            .GetType().GetTypeInfo()
            .GetField("_context", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .GetValue(dbSet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Was this on .NET? Damn, what a bad writen code. Still using nonetheless. Destiny arrives the same.

Comment: But how about complex types? or [Owned] attribute. Your code example updates only propeties and not referenced complex types

Comment: I improved a lot from this code sample, check it out at: https://github.com/EdgarSalazar/salazar-efcore-dbset-addorupdate

Comment: I understand this is an old answer, but is it really pulling in all records from the table, filtering through it in memory, and then updating the change state in the context? That is awful.

Comment: It is sad this answer got upvotes at all. It has multiple flaws, starting with a) retrieving all rows, or 2) accessing the private _context field instead of using ´dbSet.GetService.GetService<ICurrentDbContext>()´,  or 3) using a for loop on key members instead of dbSet.Find and so on...

Answer (score 6):

This solution is, I think, a simpler solution to this problem, if assuming a base entity class is a legit option. The simplicity comes from your domain entities implementing DomainEntityBase, which alleviates a lot of the complexities in the other suggested solutions.

```
public static class DbContextExtensions
{
    public static void AddOrUpdate<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet, IEnumerable<T> records) 
        where T : DomainEntityBase
    {
        foreach (var data in records)
        {
            var exists = dbSet.AsNoTracking().Any(x => x.Id == data.Id);
            if (exists)
            {
                dbSet.Update(data);
                continue;
            }
            dbSet.Add(data);
        }
    }
}

public class DomainEntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That forces you to make every model to inherit from that base, and that isn't a good idea for the domain, I think.

Comment: Good point. Note that we only use add-or-update for seeding test/reference data, and and all the entities we seed have Guid identifiers, so it happened to work well for our use case.

Comment: You return from the loop after the first update. Is it intentional?

Comment: Good catch, should have been a continue. I've updated the sample above.

Comment: Also, to address SuperJMN's concern, we use surrogate GUID-based keys for all our entities, so this happens to work for us. We balance this by creating unique "natural key" indexes to enforce the natural uniqueness of the table.

Answer (score 6):

I started with [Tjaart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43988985/3179396)'s answer and modified two things:

1. I'm using the fluent api for key designation so I'm looking for the entity's primary key instead of an attribute on the entity
2. I have change tracking turned on and was getting the error others have mentioned regarding that EF is already tracking it. This does a find on the already tracked entity and copies the values from the incoming entity to it, then updates the original entity

   ```
   public TEntity AddOrUpdate(TEntity entity)
   {
       var entityEntry = Context.Entry(entity);

       var primaryKeyName = entityEntry.Context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TEntity)).FindPrimaryKey().Properties
           .Select(x => x.Name).Single();

       var primaryKeyField = entity.GetType().GetProperty(primaryKeyName);

       var t = typeof(TEntity);
       if (primaryKeyField == null)
       {
           throw new Exception($"{t.FullName} does not have a primary key specified. Unable to exec AddOrUpdate call.");
       }
       var keyVal = primaryKeyField.GetValue(entity);
       var dbVal = DbSet.Find(keyVal);

       if (dbVal != null)
       {
           Context.Entry(dbVal).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
           DbSet.Update(dbVal);

           entity = dbVal;
       }
       else
       {
           DbSet.Add(entity);
       }

       return entity;
   }
   ```

I've been able to get decent mileage out of it so far without any problems.

I'm using this on EFCore 2.1

Answer (score 5):

There is an extension method [Upsert](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FlexLabs.EntityFrameworkCore.Upsert).

```
context.Upsert(new Role { Name = "Employee", NormalizedName = "employee" })
       .On(r => new { r.Name })
       .Run();
```

[On Github](https://github.com/artiomchi/FlexLabs.Upsert)

Comment: Unfortunately this saves changes directly in the database while an add/update updates the context. And it doesn't work when somewhere a timestamp type field is used. You should mention the restrictions of this method like described here: https://www.flexlabs.org/2018/02/adding-upsert-support-for-entity-framework-core

Comment: Does this still work in .Net Core 3.0? I'm using it with Repository pattern like this `_entities.UpsertRange(entities);` but nothing is inserted in Sqlite database.

Answer (score 5):

I don't understand why people are trying to find the primary key in the other answers.
Just pass it when you're calling the method as it's done in **EF 6** AddOrUpdate method.

```
public static TEntity AddOrUpdate<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> dbSet, DbContext context, Func<TEntity, object> identifier, TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
{
    TEntity result = dbSet.Find(identifier.Invoke(entity));
    if (result != null)
    {
        context.Entry(result).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
        dbSet.Update(result);
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        dbSet.Add(entity);
        return entity;
    }
}
```

and use it later like this:

```
dbContext.MyModels.AddOrUpdate(dbContext, model => model.Id, new MyModel() { Id = 3 });
```

Clean and performant.

Comment: `context.Entry(result).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);` this doesn't work. it fails when trying to update the primary key.

Comment: @MatthiasBurger Why would you want to update the primary key? That's impossible.

Comment: that's what the error says. And that's what you are doing. I don't want to change the PK.

Comment: I'm not doing this, the code finds the database side result by Id, if it exists we overwrite it. If not, we add it. Please tell me how are you calling the `AddOrUpdate` method. Make sure you're passing the `identifier` correctly. It should be the PK.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this extension method I created to patch our codebase for the migration to EF Core:

```
   public static void AddOrUpdate<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet, T data) where T : class
        {
            var t = typeof(T);
            PropertyInfo keyField = null;
            foreach (var propt in t.GetProperties())
            {
                var keyAttr = propt.GetCustomAttribute<KeyAttribute>();
                if (keyAttr != null)
                {
                    keyField = propt;
                    break; // assume no composite keys
                }
            }
            if (keyField == null)
            {
                throw new Exception($"{t.FullName} does not have a KeyAttribute field. Unable to exec AddOrUpdate call.");
            }
            var keyVal = keyField.GetValue(data);
            var dbVal = dbSet.Find(keyVal);
            if (dbVal != null)
            {
                dbSet.Update(data);
                return;
            }
            dbSet.Add(data);
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work, since EF Core just throws the usual tracking error. It looks like EF Core starts tracking the entity after `find()` and when `update` is called throws an error that it's already tracking that entity. It's awkward because EF may already be tracking the entity and find can grab that vs going to the DB.

Comment: I just checked this on my EF Core 1.1 project and it works just fine. The code has been working on production for since end of May.

Comment: I agree with Douglas Gaskell, this solution only works if you have change tracking disabled at the context level, which for us was not an option. See my solution below for an alternate implementation.

Comment: That's odd. Our change tracking is not disabled and yet this works for us. Maybe there is something specific to our solution that allows this to work. Not sure

Answer (score 1):

I've found a nice solution that allows you specify the property that should match. However, it doesn't take a single entity, but a list in each call. It may give you some hints on how to implement a better version that works like the good-olde one.

https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/7787e963dd0b7293ff95b28dcae92407231e0300/samples/MusicStore/Models/SampleData.cs#L48

(Code isn't mine)

Comment: It loads all existing records in memory, which is not scalable at all

Comment: Do you know a better way? ;)

Comment: https://github.com/mcshaz/PicuCalendars/blob/master/PicuCalendars/DataAccess/EFExtensions.cs, may be  [Where to run a duplicate check for an entity](//stackoverflow.com/a/16647237),

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me using Entity Framework Core  (2.0) so here's the solution that worked for me:

```
public static class DbSetExtensions
{

    public static void AddOrUpdate<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet, Expression<Func<T, object>> identifierExpression, params T[] entities) where T : class
    {
        foreach (var entity in entities)
            AddOrUpdate(dbSet, identifierExpression, entity);
    }


    public static void AddOrUpdate<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet, Expression<Func<T, object>> identifierExpression, T entity) where T : class
    {
        if (identifierExpression == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(identifierExpression));
        if (entity == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));

        var keyObject = identifierExpression.Compile()(entity);
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(
                ReplaceParameter(identifierExpression.Body, parameter),
                Expression.Constant(keyObject)),
            parameter);

        var item = dbSet.FirstOrDefault(lambda.Compile());
        if (item == null)
        {
            // easy case
            dbSet.Add(entity);
        }
        else
        {
            // get Key fields, using KeyAttribute if possible otherwise convention
            var dataType = typeof(T);
            var keyFields = dataType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<KeyAttribute>() != null).ToList();
            if (!keyFields.Any())
            {
                string idName = dataType.Name + "Id";
                keyFields = dataType.GetProperties().Where(p => 
                    string.Equals(p.Name, "Id", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || 
                    string.Equals(p.Name, idName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
            }

            // update all non key and non collection properties
            foreach (var p in typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetSetMethod() != null && p.GetGetMethod() != null))
            {
                // ignore collections
                if (p.PropertyType != typeof(string) && p.PropertyType.GetInterface(nameof(System.Collections.IEnumerable)) != null)
                    continue;

                // ignore ID fields
                if (keyFields.Any(x => x.Name == p.Name))
                    continue;

                var existingValue = p.GetValue(entity);
                if (!Equals(p.GetValue(item), existingValue))
                {
                    p.SetValue(item, existingValue);
                }
            }

            // also update key values on incoming data item where appropriate
            foreach (var idField in keyFields.Where(p => p.GetSetMethod() != null && p.GetGetMethod() != null))
            {
                var existingValue = idField.GetValue(item);
                if (!Equals(idField.GetValue(entity), existingValue))
                {
                    idField.SetValue(entity, existingValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private static Expression ReplaceParameter(Expression oldExpression, ParameterExpression newParameter)
    {
        switch (oldExpression.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
                var m = (MemberExpression)oldExpression;
                return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(newParameter, m.Member);
            case ExpressionType.New:
                var newExpression = (NewExpression)oldExpression;
                var arguments = new List<Expression>();
                foreach (var a in newExpression.Arguments)
                    arguments.Add(ReplaceParameter(a, newParameter));
                var returnValue = Expression.New(newExpression.Constructor, arguments.ToArray());
                return returnValue;
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException("Unknown expression type for AddOrUpdate: " + oldExpression.NodeType);
        }
    }
}
```

You may need to update the ReplaceParameter() method if you have a more complicated identifierExpression.  Simple property accessors will work fine with this implementation. e.g.:

```
context.Projects.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Name, new Project { ... })
context.Projects.AddOrUpdate(x => new { x.Name, x.Description }, new Project { ... })
```

Then context.SaveChanges() will commit the data to the database

Comment: Added a line at the end to ensure context.SaveChanges() actually commits the data to the database

Comment: The property 'Id' on entity type 'Contact' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified. To change the principal of an existing entity with an identifying foreign key first delete the dependent and invoke 'SaveChanges' then associate the dependent with the new principal.

Comment: This throws the following exception for me:
The instance of entity type 'X' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id', 'Text'} is already being tracked

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution based on other solutions from this thread.

- Supports composite keys
- Supports shadow-property keys.
- Stays within EF Core realm and doesn't use reflection.
- Change _appDb to your context.

```cs
        public object PrimaryKeyValues<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
        {
            var properties = _appDb.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TEntity)).FindPrimaryKey().Properties;

            var entry = _appDb.Entry(entity);

            var values = properties?.Select(p => entry.Property(p.Name).CurrentValue);

            if (values?.Count() == 1)
                return values.Single();

            return values?.ToArray();
        }


        public async Task<TEntity> AddOrUpdateAsync<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
        {
            var pkValue = PrimaryKeyValues(entity);

            if (pkValue == null)
            {
                throw new Exception($"{typeof(TEntity).FullName} does not have a primary key specified. Unable to exec AddOrUpdateAsync call.");
            }

            if ((await _appDb.FindAsync(typeof(TEntity), pkValue)) is TEntity dbEntry)
            {
                _appDb.Entry(dbEntry).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
                _appDb.Update(dbEntry);

                entity = dbEntry;
            }
            else
            {
                _appDb.Add(entity);
            }

            return entity;
        }
```

---

### Update - Add Or Update Range

Complete solution.
Doesn't support keys that are shadow properties

`DbContextExtensions.cs`

```cs
        // FIND ALL
        // ===============================================================
        /// <summary>
        /// Tries to get all entities by their primary keys. Return all/partial/empty array of database entities.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TEntity"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="dbContext"></param>
        /// <param name="args"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static async Task<TEntity[]> FindAllAsync<TEntity>(this DbContext dbContext, IEnumerable<TEntity> args) where TEntity : class
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => { 
                var dbParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), typeof(TEntity).Name);

                var properties = dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TEntity)).FindPrimaryKey()?.Properties;

                if (properties == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException($"{typeof(TEntity).FullName} does not have a primary key specified.");

                if (args == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException($"Entities to find argument cannot be null");

                if (!args.Any())
                    return Enumerable.Empty<TEntity>().ToArray();

                var aggregatedExpression = args.Select(entity =>
                {
                    var entry = dbContext.Entry(entity);

                    return properties.Select(p =>
                    {
                        var dbProp = dbParameter.Type.GetProperty(p.Name); 
                        var left = Expression.Property(dbParameter, dbProp); 

                        var argValue = entry.Property(p.Name).CurrentValue;
                        var right = Expression.Constant(argValue);

                        return Expression.Equal(left, right);
                    })
                    .Aggregate((acc, next) => Expression.And(acc, next));
                })
                .Aggregate((acc, next) => Expression.OrElse(acc, next));

                var whereMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "Where" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2);
                MethodInfo genericWhereMethod = whereMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TEntity));

                var whereLambda = Expression.Lambda(aggregatedExpression, dbParameter);

                var set = dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
                var func = whereLambda.Compile();

                var result = genericWhereMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { set, func}) as IEnumerable<TEntity>;

                return result.ToArray();
            });
        }

        // ADD OR UPDATE - RANGE - ASYNC
        // ===============================================================
        /// <summary>
        /// Foreach entity in a range, adds it when it doesn't exist otherwise updates it. Bases decision on Pk.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TEntity"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="dbContext"></param>
        /// <param name="entities"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static async Task<(int AddedCount, int UpdatedCount)> AddOrUpdateRangeAsync<TEntity>(this DbContext dbContext, IEnumerable<TEntity> entities) where TEntity : class
        {
            var existingEntitiesHashes = (await dbContext.FindAllAsync(entities)).Select(x =>
            {
                dbContext.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Detached;
                return dbContext.PrimaryKeyHash(x);
            });

            var (True, False) = entities.DivideOn(x => existingEntitiesHashes.Contains(dbContext.PrimaryKeyHash(x)));

            dbContext.UpdateRange(True);
            dbContext.AddRange(False);

            return (AddedCount: False.Count(), UpdatedCount: True.Count());
        }


        // ADD OR UPDATE - ASYNC
        // ===============================================================
        /// <summary>
        /// Adds when not existing otherwise updates an entity. Bases decision on Pk.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TEntity"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="dbContext"></param>
        /// <param name="entity"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static async Task AddOrUpdateAsync<TEntity>(this DbContext dbContext, TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
            => await dbContext.AddOrUpdateRangeAsync(new TEntity[] { entity });

        // PK HASH
        // ===============================================================
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the compounded hash string of all primary keys of the entity
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TTarget"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="dbContext"></param>
        /// <param name="entity"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string PrimaryKeyHash<TTarget>(this DbContext dbContext, TTarget entity)
        {
            var properties = dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TTarget)).FindPrimaryKey().Properties;

            var entry = dbContext.Entry(entity);

            return properties.Select(p => Crypto.HashGUID(entry.Property(p.Name).CurrentValue))
                             .Aggregate(string.Empty, (acc, next) => acc += next);
        }
```

`Crypto.cs`

```cs
    public class Crypto
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// RETURNS A HASH AS A GUID BASED ON OBJECT.TOSTRING()
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string HashGUID(object obj)
        {
            string text = string.Empty;
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5CryptoServiceProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] bytes = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(obj.ToString());
            byte[] array = md5CryptoServiceProvider.ComputeHash(bytes);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                text += Convert.ToString(array[i], 16).PadLeft(2, '0');
            }
            md5CryptoServiceProvider.Clear();
            return text.PadLeft(32, '0');
        }
    }
```

`IEnumerableExtensions.cs`

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Divides into two based on predicate
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="source"></param>
        /// <param name="predicate"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static (IEnumerable<T> True, IEnumerable<T> False) DivideOn<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
            => (source.Where(x => predicate(x)), source.Where(x => !predicate(x)));
```

Comment if use it (ﾉ◕ヮ◕)ﾉ✲ﾟ｡⋆