# Entity Framework Core seed update

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I am new to Ef Core. Trying to seed data while migration update.

He is how i did it

First created an initializer class:

```
using AcademicNet.Data.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AcademicNet.Data
{
public class PersonInitializer
{
    private AcademicPortalContext _context;

    public PersonInitializer(AcademicPortalContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }



    public async Task Seed()
    {
        if(!_context.PersonCategoryStatuses.Any())
        {
            _context.AddRange(_personCategoryStatus);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        if (!_context.PersonCategories.Any())
        {
            _context.AddRange(_personCategory);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        if (!_context.People.Any())
        {
            _context.AddRange(_people);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }

    List<PersonCategory> _personCategory = new List<PersonCategory>
    {
        new PersonCategory()
        {
            Name = "Internal Person Category",
            Description = "Silahkan diganti redaksi ini",
            PersonCategoryStatusId = 2,
            StartDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
            ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow
        }
    };

    List<Person> _people = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person()
        {
            FirstName = "Jannen",
            LastName = "Siahaan",
            Email = "j.siahaan@any.com",
            DateAdd = DateTime.UtcNow,
            ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow
        }
    };

    List<PersonCategoryStatus> _personCategoryStatus = new List<PersonCategoryStatus>
    {
        new PersonCategoryStatus()
        {
            Status = "Baru"
        },
        new PersonCategoryStatus()
        {
            Status = "Valid"
        },
        new PersonCategoryStatus()
        {
            Status = "Expired"
        }
    };
}
}
```

2. At the ConfigurationServices in Startup.cs add this:

```
services.AddTransient<PersonInitializer>();
```

3. At the parameter of Configure method at the Startup.cs add this injection:

`public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
                              IHostingEnvironment env, 
                              ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
                              PersonInitializer personSeeder,
                              AcademicPortalIdentityInitializer identitySeeder)`
4. At the end of this "public void Configure" after app.UseMvc()

`personSeeder.Seed().Wait();`

suppose i have run the migration

and want to add a new PersonCategoryStatus as 'inValid' later. How can i acheive this.

```
new PersonCategoryStatus
List<PersonCategoryStatus> _personCategoryStatus = new List<PersonCategoryStatus>
    {
        new PersonCategoryStatus()
        {
            Status = "Baru"
        },
        new PersonCategoryStatus()
        {
            Status = "Valid"
        },
        new PersonCategoryStatus()
        {
            Status = "Expired"
        },
        new PersonCategoryStatus()
        {
            Status = "Invalid"
        }
    };
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: My bad on the AddOrUpdate discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208580/what-happened-to-addorupdate-in-ef-7)

Answer (score 0):

At Seed() body instead of this:

```
if(!_context.PersonCategoryStatuses.Any())
```

you should iterate over **_personCategoryStatus** collection and do a upsert operation for each possible status.