# AddOrUpdate() method in asp.net Core 2

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

How can I access to `AddOrUpdate()` method when I using `ASP.NET Core 2`?

There is `AddOrUpdate()` in `EntityFramework 6` in `System.Data.Entity.Migrations` namespace. But when I want to use this method in `ASP.NET Core 2`, I cannot find it.

Comment: Check this out... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208580/what-happened-to-addorupdate-in-ef-7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happened to AddOrUpdate in EF 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208580/what-happened-to-addorupdate-in-ef-7)

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want

```cs
public static class DbSetExtension
{
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
    public static TEntity FindEntity<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> dbSet, TEntity entity, bool noTracking = false) where TEntity : class
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
        }

        var dbContext = dbSet.GetService<ICurrentDbContext>().Context;
        var entityEntry = dbContext.Entry(entity);
        var entityType = entityEntry.Metadata;
        var primaryKey = entityType.FindPrimaryKey();
        if (primaryKey == null)
        {
            return (noTracking ? dbSet.AsNoTracking() : dbSet).FirstOrDefault(item => item.Equals(entity));
        }

        var ids = primaryKey.Properties.Select(item => item.PropertyInfo.GetValue(entity)).ToArray();
        var result = dbSet.Find(ids);
        if (noTracking && result != null)
        {
            dbContext.Entry(result).State = EntityState.Detached;
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
    public static async ValueTask<TEntity> FindEntityAsync<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> dbSet, TEntity entity, bool noTracking = false)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
        }

        var dbContext = dbSet.GetService<ICurrentDbContext>().Context;
        var entityEntry = dbContext.Entry(entity);
        var entityType = entityEntry.Metadata;
        var primaryKey = entityType.FindPrimaryKey();
        if (primaryKey == null)
        {
            return await (noTracking ? dbSet.AsNoTracking() : dbSet).FirstOrDefaultAsync(item => item.Equals(entity));
        }

        var ids = primaryKey.Properties.Select(item => item.PropertyInfo.GetValue(entity)).ToArray();
        var result = await dbSet.FindAsync(ids);
        if (noTracking && result != null)
        {
            dbContext.Entry(result).State = EntityState.Detached;
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
    public static EntityEntry<TEntity> Update<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> dbSet, TEntity entity, bool? includeOrExclude = null,
        params string[] propertyNames) where TEntity : class
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
        }

        var entityEntry = dbSet.Update(entity);
        if (includeOrExclude != null)
        {
            foreach (var property in entityEntry.Properties)
            {
                if (includeOrExclude.Value ^ propertyNames?.Contains(property.Metadata.PropertyInfo.Name) == true)
                {
                    property.IsModified = false;
                }
            }
        }

        return entityEntry;
    }

    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
    public static EntityEntry<TEntity> AddOrUpdate<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> dbSet, TEntity entity, bool? includeOrExclude = null,
        params string[] propertyNames) where TEntity : class
    {
        if (dbSet.FindEntity(entity, true) == null)
        {
            return dbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        return dbSet.Update(entity, includeOrExclude, propertyNames);
    }

    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
    public static async ValueTask<EntityEntry<TEntity>> AddOrUpdateAsync<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> dbSet, TEntity entity, bool? includeOrExclude = null,
        params string[] propertyNames) where TEntity : class
    {
        if (await dbSet.FindEntityAsync(entity, true) == null)
        {
            return await dbSet.AddAsync(entity);
        }

        return dbSet.Update(entity, includeOrExclude, propertyNames);
    }
}
```

I've omitted the comments for brevity.

Use like this

```cs
var people = new People {
Id=1,
Name="Tom",
ChangeTime=DateTimeOffset.Now
AddTime=DateTimeOffset.Now,
};

await dbContext.AddOrUpdateAsync(people, false, nameof(people.AddTime));
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

or

```
await dbContext.AddOrUpdateAsync(people, true, nameof(people.Name), nameof(people.ChangeTime));
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

You can also use its synchronization method.

I was in the "Microsoft. EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.1" and "Microsoft. EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.7" test normal.

You may need more: [Saving an explicit value during add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/explicit-values-generated-properties#saving-an-explicit-value-during-add).

If the entity uses auto-generated key values. see also: [Saving single entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities#saving-single-entities).

If there is any omission, please let me know. Thank you.