The AspNetUserRoles table was cleared during migrations
I'm developing a website with ASP.NET Core 8 Web API, SQL Server, utilizing the identity framework. The database contains various tables such as AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles, AspNetUserRoles, Brands, and more. Since I have already populated the database with real data, I prefer not to drop the table. When I need to make modifications to the database, I typically use command lines. However, each time I update the table, the AspNetUserRoles table gets cleared. How can I preserve the data in the userRoles table?
Here are the command lines I tried.
dotnet ef migrations add updateUserTable

dotnet ef database update

There is userRoles table after I execute these command lines but the userRoles table is empty.
I'm using VSCode for developing tool.


Hi @Terrance, have you checked this answer?

Is this what's happening? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52517573/why-seeded-roles-are-deleted-on-every-migration-in-asp-net-core-2-1.

I checked it, it worked. How can I award you the bounty?

You must create a new migration to incrementally update the database schema whenever you make a change to the model. Run the command below:
dotnet ef migrations add AddNewMig - This command creates a new migration called AddNewMig which EF should recognise is an update to the exsiting tables (and therefore the migration should only be and update)
dotnet ef database update AddNewMig - This will then run the AddNewMig migration
Reference: Migrations Overview

Is that legacy code? You can follow several steps to find the problem:

Check your OnModelCreating on your DbContext - is your code has truncate logic.
Check your seeder (if you have one) - in my projects I configure my seeder to truncate all tables if env=staging.
And if this project is new, can you send migrations scripts to here or to GitHub? The community can review that.

